# Calculate matrix determinant with partial pivoting Gauss in C

Tags: c, matrix, partial, gaussian, determinants

I'm trying to make a simple console application in C which will calculate the determinant of a Matrix using the Gauss partial pivoting elimination method. The 2 problems that I have are :
- someone told me that there are certain matrix-es that don't work with this method ( mathematically speaking ), after reading articles on google, i could not find what is that special case
- after a lot of tests I found out that my program is not working for some matrix-es, after 2 days of "wasting" time editing and undoing, i could not find the problem.

Any type of improvements are more than welcomed. I'm just starting with C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>

// calculate biggest element on column

int indice_max(int dim, int col, float coloana[20][20]) {

    float max = 0;
    int indice;

    for(int i = 1; i <= dim; i++)
        if(fabs(max) < fabs(coloana[i][col])) {
            max = coloana[i][col];
            indice = i;
        }

    return indice;

}

// permute 2 lines

void permutare_linie(int linie1, int linie2, int dim, float matrice[20][20]) {

    float aux;

    for(int i = 1; i <= dim; i++) {
        aux = matrice[linie1][i];
        matrice[linie1][i] = matrice[linie2][i];
        matrice[linie2][i] = aux;
    }

}

// print matrix

void afisare_matrice(int dimensiune, float matrice[20][20], int lpiv) {

    for(int i = 1; i<= dimensiune; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= dimensiune; j++) {
            if(i == lpiv)
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), BACKGROUND_GREEN);
            else
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE );
            printf("%4.2f ", matrice[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}


void main(void) {

    float matrice[20][20];
    int dimensiune ;
    float rezultat = 1;
    float pivot;
    int lpiv;
    int cpiv;
    int optiune;
    while(1) {

        // MENU

        printf("ALEGET OPTIUNEA:\n");
        printf("1) Calculate matrix determinant\n");
        printf("2) Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &optiune);

        if(optiune == 1) {

            // Read determinant dimension

            printf("Matrix dimension:");
            scanf("%d", &dimensiune);

            // Read determinant

            for(int i = 1; i <= dimensiune; i++)
                for(int j = 1; j <= dimensiune; j++) {
                    printf("M[%d][%d]=", i, j);
                    scanf("%f", &matrice[i][j]);
            }

            // pivot initial coords

            lpiv = 1;
            cpiv = 1;

            printf("\n----- Entered Matrix -----\n\n");
            afisare_matrice(dimensiune, matrice, 0);
            printf("\n");

            for(int pas = 1; pas <= dimensiune - 1; pas++) {

                if(fabs(matrice[lpiv][cpiv]) > fabs(matrice[indice_max(dimensiune, cpiv, matrice)][cpiv])) {
                    permutare_linie(lpiv, indice_max(dimensiune, cpiv, matrice), dimensiune, matrice);
                    rezultat = -(rezultat);
                }

                pivot = matrice[lpiv][cpiv];


                for(int inm = 1; inm <= dimensiune; inm++) {
                    matrice[lpiv][inm] = matrice[lpiv][inm] / pivot;
                }

                rezultat *= fabs(pivot);

                // transform matrix to a superior triangular 
                for(int l = lpiv+1; l <= dimensiune; l++)
                    for(int c=cpiv+1; c <= dimensiune; c++) {
                        matrice[l][c] -= matrice[l][cpiv] * matrice[lpiv][c] / matrice[lpiv][cpiv];
                    }

                for(int i = lpiv + 1; i <= dimensiune; i++)
                    matrice[i][cpiv] = 0;
                // afisam rezultat / pas

                printf("----- Step %d -----\n\n", pas);
                afisare_matrice(dimensiune, matrice, lpiv);
                printf("\nResult after step %d : %4.2f\n\n", pas, rezultat);
                lpiv++;
                cpiv++;
            }

            // final result

            rezultat = rezultat * matrice[dimensiune][dimensiune];
            printf("----- REZULTAT FINAL -----\n\n");
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
            printf("Rezultat = %4.2f\nRezultat rotunjit:%4.0f\n\n", rezultat, floorf(rezultat * 100 +  0.5) / 100);
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE );

        }
        else {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, go to the library and find a book on numerical methods, such as Numerical Methods, Burden&Faires,if I am not mistaken and see their C implementation for Gauss elimination, HTH

Comment: It's explained in the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_matrix) "A square matrix that is not invertible is called singular or degenerate. A square matrix is singular if and only if its determinant is 0. Singular matrices are rare in the sense that if you pick a random square matrix, it will almost surely not be singular."

Comment: No need to even go to the library!  Check out chapter 2: http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php

Comment: @user786653 Your explanation says when a matrix is not invertible. A singular matrix is when it's determinant is 0, but I need to calculate the determinant to see if it is 0 or not. There are code examples on the web for this procedure, but they dont do the same steps my university professor is doing.

Comment: See @anatolygs answer, a singular matrix will have a zero column at some point, there's no need to explicitly calculate the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does some division:

```
matrice[lpiv][inm] = matrice[lpiv][inm] / pivot;
```

If it happens to divide by zero, an error will occur. I guess this will happen for the zero matrix.

It seems that your code is actually trying to invert the matrix, not just calculate the determinant.

Comment: Of course, I thought about one of the elements on diagonal to be 0, but didn't thought they could be 0 after the operations done to convert the matrix to an superior triangular one. Thanks. I think I found the other problem too. I'm searching for the max element on the whole column, not only below the pivot.